# How do pilots manage metric altitude?

Tags: air-traffic-control, international, units

A minority of the world, specifically Russia and China, uses the metric system in aviation. ATC will tell the pilots to "climb to 900 meters height".

How do pilots of international flights manage this? Do they request the ATC to provide altitude in feet, or do they perform the conversion manually and dial in the altitude in feet to the autopilot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In areas where the ATC provides the altitude in meter (China (PRC), North Korea, and Russia), depending on the equipment (altimeter), the pilot can determine what to do:

- In case of older aircraft, where the altimeter is calibrated in feet, the pilots use a conversion card for determining the altitude in feet, before dialing in the altitude to the autopilot.

[image: Conversion Card]

Source: aerosavvy.com

Note: The conversion charts are standardized for the airspace and the pilots have to use it. For Chinese airspace refer [FAA document on Chinese RVSM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/separation_standards/rvsm/documents/Pilot_Opr_Guidance_Mtrl_China_RVSM_2007101014251255.pdf)

- In case of modern aircraft displays, the altimeter can be made to display altitude in imperial (feet) or metric (meter) units.

Comment: In the latter case, it is critical to remember which way it is set!

Answer (score -3):

Here is a page with all the info on this subject: http://aerosavvy.com/metric-imperial/

> Altimeter Calibration: mb, hPa & inHg
>   Altimeters can be set using hPa or inHg.
>
> Altimeters can be set using hPa (mb) or inHg.
>
> In order to calibrate our altimeters for varying atmospheric pressure, we set the current pressure reported by ground stations. Pressure is reported in inches of mercury (inHg), hectopascals (hPa), or millibars (mb). North America and Japan use the inches of mercury measurement. Hectopascals dominate the rest of the aviation world (millibars and hectopascals are equal). For years, altimeter manufactures have provided two calibration windows for hPa and inHg. This makes setting our altimeters easy no matter where we fly.  Just dial the reported pressure into one of the windows and you’re all set! Newer, digital altimeters have a button to switch between units. I like the older ones, they’re easier to set.
>   Measuring Altitude: Feet vs. Meters
>
> Here’s where things get tricky. Because of the proliferation of American and British aircraft during the early years of aviation, the imperial foot became standard for altitude measurement. China (PRC), North Korea, and Russia, however, use meters for altitude measurement.
>
> As luck would have it, I often fly over Chinese, Russian, and North Korean airspace. The altimeters in our older aircraft, like the 767, are calibrated in feet. When flying into metric airspace, we use a conversion card. When Shanghai Control clears us to descend to 3600 meters, we check the card and descend to the equivalent: 11,800 feet. Does this sound like a pain in the you-know-where? It is!
>
> During rush hour at airports like Shanghai and Beijing, the controllers rattle off clearances very fast. They will often assign us a heading, speed and metric altitude all in one shot. Doing the metric altitude conversion adds an additional task to an already challenging environment. We stay on our toes in metric airspace! The good news is that newer generation airplanes have a switch that can change the aircraft’s native altimetry display from imperial to metric units. When crossing into metric airspace, the crew hits the switch and the airplane understands the metric system. This reduces crew workload considerably.
>   Distance Across The Ground
>
> World-wide, the nautical mile (nm) is the standard for measuring the distance an aircraft travels across the ground. That’s nice and easy and it makes me happy. :)
>
> Other lateral measurements are a mess. Most of the world measures runway length in meters while North America uses feet. Most of the world measures airport visibility in meters. North America? Not nautical miles, not meters, but statute miles! Huh?? Not to worry, North America changes back to feet when measuring Runway Visual Range (runway visibility measured with a laser), while the rest of the world sticks with meters. Confused? I sure am, and I do this for a living!
>   Wind speed: Knots vs. Meters/Second
>
> When reporting weather, airports in China and Russia state the surface winds in meters per second (m/s). They love this metric stuff! The rest of the world reports wind in knots (nautical miles / hour). Converting is easy:
>
> 1 m/s ≈ 2 kts
>
> Double the m/s and we are close to knots. If Shanghai tower tells me the winds are 7 meters per second, I know they are blowing just a little shy of 14 knots. I can land in that much wind. Any more than that and I’ll let my first officer do it!
>   Is flying safe with all these different units?
>
> Yes!  Pilots flying international routes deal with this assortment of units daily. We can juggle them in our sleep. While it’s certainly an added challenge, it’s an important part of our occupation. There are very well defined standards and procedures that pilots use to work with the different units. Flying continues to be the safest form of transportation available.

Basically, it is that either the pilots have tables to convert units or the instruments can show both types. In either case, it would be very easy to follow the ATC instructions.

Comment: You may sum up the quote. Yes it answer the question extensivly, but it also add a lot of additionnal informations. You should put only the relevant information in your answer and provide the link for further readings. It would ease the reading of your answer

Comment: Now you've just copied and pasted the whole thing with no attribution and no effort on your part.  The OP can use Google for that.  This is no how SE.Aviation works.